# is there any CHM/html reference for unix/linux C functions (like in man)?

Tags: c, documentation

i need such reference preferable in CHM format or any other fast-access format. I need all *nix functions + pthread + all sockets (network) functions.
Searching the internet i did not find any, so working from my home on my unix projects is too slow.. i need to man() all the funcs i need in my remote shell.

Thank you

Comment: as a workaround, you can install Cygwin on your home machine

Comment: @Vlad, thanks i've installed cygwin+man(by default) but i did not found any options to install BASE documentation. i found docs options for pthread and some other lib, but standard command 'man socket' still did not find anything

Comment: Simply typing the name of a function into Google often works.

Comment: Thomas i will be fired if i will work at such speeds developing a project.

Comment: @Sergey: try to install the needed documentation through the graphical frontend setup.exe

Comment: @Vlad, yes that is what i am talking about. i firstly install the default options then executed setup.exe and tryed to find way to install something other. i found dev/doc/sys trees but they dont contain nothing about base documentation. but i found pthread lib docs in /doc tree.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than reading Linux-specific man pages I would simply read the documentation in the standard:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html

Comment: thanks, good link. i will convert this to chm format.at least i will try.chm is fastest development help format.

Answer (score 2):

I don`t know if such exist. You can build one by yourself - [man2html](http://linux.die.net/man/1/man2html) ( available on Unix and Linux ) will produce a html version which can be later converted to chm with [HTML Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks i dont know about html -> chm format soft.

Comment: well, as i see there is no way to add html files dir, only the html files by single... so there is the place to write some scripts to make this work for entire directory where each function have their html page alone.

Comment: The technology has its limitations. Probably because it must be converted to single file ( chm ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [there](http://onnerby.se/~daniel/chm/) is one since at least 2011. ;-)

(http://onnerby.se/~daniel/chm/)